# Modeling Event Booking Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

New to stack! so Hello there ! I'm making a sample event booking app, that has event check out using stripe.

My set up is below

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :tickets, :inverse_of => :event, dependent: :destroy
end


class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :event, :inverse_of => :tickets
end 


class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :event
   belongs_to :ticket, :inverse_of => :bookings
   has_one :sale, :inverse_of => :booking
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :booking, :inverse_of => :sale
    belongs_to :ticket
end  


class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_event
  before_filter :load_ticket

  def index
    @bookings = @event.bookings
  end

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  private

  def load_event
    @event =  Event.find(params[:event_id])
  end
  def load_ticket
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:ticket_id])
  end

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:buyer_name, :phone, :address, :order_quantity,:total_amount)
  end
end



class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_event
  before_filter :load_booking
  before_filter :load_ticket

 def new
  end

 def pickup
 @sale = Sale.find_by!(guid: params[:guid])
 @booking = @sale.booking
 end

 def complete 
 @sale = Sale.find_by!(guid: params[:guid])
 @booking = @sale.booking
 end



if sale.save
  StripeCharger.perform_async(sale.guid)
  render json: { guid: sale.guid }
else
  errors = sale.errors.full_messages
  render json: {
    error: errors.join(" ")
  }, status: 400
end
end

def status
 sale = Sale.find_by!(guid: params[:guid])

 render json: { status: sale.state }
end



private

def load_event
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
end

def load_booking
   @booking = @event.bookings.find(params[:booking_id])
end

def load_ticket
  @ticket = @booking.ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
end
end


            #Stripe Checkout Routes
```

I left out a view minimal details within the models . But basically What I am trying to do is have a user enter Name, and quantity of the ticket and from submitin the booking redirect to the transaction new, in which I can carry out the sale model with Stripe Check out.

My ultimate goal of everything is to get the bookings quantity input multiplied with the ticket price to get a total amount to carry through Stripe. Do anyone have any suggestions on how to improve this break down. Of modeling a events, tickets, bookings to check out type of example. Sorry if how I'm breaking it down is noobish, I'm attempting to wrap my head around accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In transaction controller you don't need find on @booking.ticket

```
def load_ticket
  @ticket = @booking.ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
end
```

Since @booking has only one ticket, you just need @booking.ticket

Comment: your a genius! Many Thanks!